# How to set Default view page size to 50 for admin Order Grid : Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

I want to set the Default view per page size to 50 in the admin order view. I tried by saving the view but that is only per user. 
I want to set the **per page size = 50** for all the users.

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2):

I can do this by a small change in the ui_component of that grid . Add this code to the paging tag in listing_top container in the ui_componnent 
`

```
<item name="sizesConfig" xsi:type="array">
          <item name="value" xsi:type="number">50</item>
 </item>
```

The content of paging tag should be something like this

```
<paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">pin_license_listing.pin_license_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="sizesConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="value" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">pin_license_listing.pin_license_listing.pin_license_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
</paging>
```

Comment: works like a charm, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this via the magento backend under `Store > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog` under the `Storefront` fieldset there is an option for this `Products per Page on Grid Default Value` as well as list. You can also set the `Products per Page on Grid Allowed Values` as well by default these are `12,24,36`

[image]

Something to keep in mind the more products that load on the first page view could increase the latency of the site for it having to load all those products.

Comment: I am looking for Order grid in admin panel. The configurations you mention is for frontend.